# Knockout.js writing internal function on observable array push

Tags: knockout.js

**(Updated/Edited Question)**
I am following a Knockout.js tutorial and have come across a problem while trying to update my observable array.

Below is my html for displaying a list :

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: shoppingCart">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: price"></td>
            <td><button data-bind="click: $root.removeProduct.bind($root)">Remove</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

And this is the viewmodel:

```
function Product(name, price) {
        this.name = ko.observable(name);
        this.price = ko.observable(price);
    }


    function PersonViewModel() {

        this.shoppingCart = ko.observableArray([
            new Product("Beer", 9.99),
            new Product("Peanuts", 1.09),
            new Product("COke",1.29)
        ]);

        this.addProduct = function () {
            this.shoppingCart.push(new Product("More Beer", "10.99"));            
        };
    };
```

This code below is writing an internal function on my UI instead of adding new item on my **shoppingCart** list.

Comment: Please, update your answer following this guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @JotaBe I believe you are asking me to update my "question" and not my "answer". Anyway, I found a solution to my issue which I will update my question with. Thanks.

Comment: You're right, I meant your question. And you should still do it. Even without seeing the rest of the code, and the HTML, even if your own answer is working, that doesn't look a good idea at all. If you'd be so kind to modify your Q, I, or someone else, could give you better advice. Try to read your Q&A as if you hadn't read the book, or worked on the code sample, and you'll understand my point.

Comment: I am not being rude by not updating the question here but the question seems alright to me. That is why I put the question this way in the first place. Can you please clarify which part of the question is confusing for you?

Comment: Neither I think you are trying to be rude ;) I just want to help you to write better questions. Show the viewmodel definition code, with the shoppiongCart and addProduct members (the rest doesn't matter for the question). Show the part of HTML which relates to that viewmodel (probably an element with a foreach and a button, or something like that). Don't mention a book that we cannot read. And finally don't simply say "it's not working for me": explain what you expect to happend, and what happens. Believe me, even if it's working, your answer is a bad one - update your Q and I'll explain. Tnks

Comment: Thanks @JotaBe. I have updated the question as you advised. Regarding what is not working, I had mentioned that the code was writing an internal javascript function on my UI instead of adding item to the list :).

Answer (score 0):

Replacing

`this.shoppingCart.push(new Product("More Beer", "10.99"));`

with

`this.shoppingCart.push(ko.toJS(new Product("More Beer", "10.99")));`

seems to be solving the issue.